# C++ set and get method not producing values?

Tags: c++, vector

i have these set and get methods declared in my main cpp file

```
void issuesofRelevance::setApproach(int Approach) {

approach = Approach;

}

int issuesofRelevance::getApproach() {

return approach;

}
void issuesofRelevance::setSignifiance(int Significance) {

significance = Significance;

}

int issuesofRelevance::getSignificance() {

return significance;

}
```

The following H file is attatched in which I call the setMethods in its constructor.

```
class  issuesofRelevance
{
  public:
     std::vector<std::string> issueName;
     int significance;
     int approach;
     std::vector<std::string> newList;

    issuesofRelevance(std::vector<std::string> issueName, int significance, int approach){

        issueName = issueName;
        significance = significance;
        approach = approach;
        setApproach(15);
        setSignifiance(15);

    }

     issuesofRelevance();

     void setIssues();
     std::string getIssues();


      void setApproach(int x);
      void setSignifiance(int);

      int getApproach();
      int getSignificance();
      };
```

I call the get functions in main int() as such

```
cout << object.getApproach();
cout << object.getSignificance();
```

However, when i go to run the code in the console I get no output when it should return the values of 10 and 15. Im unsure as to why this is occuring

Thankyou.

my full main as requested

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { //takes in n, number of electorates, and m, the number of campagian days 

issuesofRelevance newIssues(newIssues.issueName, newIssues.significance, newIssues.approach);
return 0;
Party party;
Person person;
Electrorates electorate;
string numberofElectoratesAsString = argv[1]; //number of electorates taking as a argument 
string DaysOfElectionAsString = argv[2]; //takes in argument 2

int numberofElectorates =  std::stoi(numberofElectoratesAsString);
int DaysOfElection =  std::stoi(DaysOfElectionAsString );


cout << "Number of electorates: " << electorate.assignID(electorate.numberofElectorates(numberofElectorates));
cout << "Stance: " << person.setinitalStance(numberofElectorates, DaysOfElection) << endl;
newIssues.setIssues(); 
cout<<newIssues.getApproach()<< " "<<newIssues.getSignificance();



return 0;
}
```

default constructor

```
issuesofRelevance::issuesofRelevance(){
}
```

Comment: if you use getter/setter, associate member can be private.

Comment: better to have const getter.

Comment: `approach = approach;` is noop. (self assign argement), and member is set afterward with `setApproach(15)` making parameter useless.

Comment: Please try expanding your code into a small program we could compile and try for ourselves. As it stands, it is not clear (to me) why you're seeing no output when streaming an `int` to `std::cout` - regardless of where that `int` came from.

Comment: There is also nothing in that code which sets any value to `10` (the constructor that accepts multiple arguments sets values to `15`, and no definition is provided for the constructor that accepts no argument).   So, even if output was produced, the information you haven't provided means that nobody can guess why you expect a value of `10`.   Read up on providing a [mcve] - if you don't, you are denying people information that they would need if they are to have any chance of helping you.

Comment: @AdrianMole ive added all this to the end of my question if you'd like to look at it

Comment: You have an unwanted `return 0;` statement as the second line of your `main` function! There are also a number of other errors: like what do you expect the passed values to be in your first line of that `main`?

Comment: id expected them to be the name of the issue, and the approach and signifiance being 10 and 10

Comment: @AdrianMole I am trying to learn

Comment: @AdrianMole I am pleased to say that with your help i have done it!

Comment: @BaoLing OK, well I am happy to have helped. But trying to initialize a class object using members of that object as parameters is really not going to achieve anything useful.